# cleanup buffer after struct to bytes.Buffer{}

Tags: go

I am using the following to save structs - very many in short time(database read and write). Do I need to clear the buffer or will it be cleaned up right after by garbage collection?

Or should dI use `buffer.Reset()`

```
func ToBytes(p interface{}) []byte {
    buf := bytes.Buffer{}
    enc := gob.NewEncoder(&buf)
    err := enc.Encode(p)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("uncompressed size (bytes): ", len(buf.Bytes()))
    return buf.Bytes()
}
```

Comment: If you are asking whether the contents of the buffer will be cleared by garbage collection for security purposes, then no, garbage collection will not clear the contents. If you are asking whether the buffers will be freed, then yes, the buffers will be freed.

Comment: Carefully consider that your code is leaking the underlying storage and that a call to Reset would not do anything about that. https://pkg.go.dev/bytes#Buffer.Bytes

Comment: Thanks @mh-cbon How would you do it then?

Comment: btw, using multiple gob encoder instance for each message is wasteful. Each resulting encoded message will contain a copy of the type specification required by the gob implementation to decode a stream. This is a lot of duplicated data...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`buf` will be cleaned by the GC, no need to call `buf.Reset()`. `buf.Reset()` can be used if you want to reuse `buf` after you have already used it once.

For example:

```golang
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var buf bytes.Buffer

    fmt.Fprint(&buf, "Hello")
    fmt.Println(buf.String()) // Prints "Hello"

    fmt.Fprintln(&buf, " World")
    fmt.Println(buf.String()) // Prints "Hello world"

    buf.Reset()

    fmt.Fprintln(&buf, "Reused!!!")
    fmt.Println(buf.String()) // Prints "Reused!!!"
}
```

> I am using the following to save structs - very many in short time(database read and write)

If allocation of `buf` turns out to be a performance issue, you could reuse `buf` lifting it to a higher scope and passing it in as variable. For example:

```golang
func main() {
    var buf bytes.Buffer

    for(...) {
        ...
        ToBytes(someVar, &buf)
        ...
    }
}

func ToBytes(p interface{}, buf *bytes.Buffer) []byte {
    buf.Reset()
    enc := gob.NewEncoder(buf)
    err := enc.Encode(p)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("uncompressed size (bytes): ", len(buf.Bytes()))
    return buf.Bytes()
}
```